# Error: The argument type 'void Function(String, DownloadTaskStatus, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String, int, int)'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
typedef DownloadManagerCallback<T> = void Function(
    DownloadTaskStatus? status, int progress, String? taskId);

class DownloadManager {
  DownloadManager(this.api, this.notifications) {
    FlutterDownloader.initialize(
      debug: false,
    ).then((_) {
      _bindBackgroundIsolate();
      FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
    });
  }
```

flutter 3.3.2 , dart 2.18.1
Trying to build but have this problem

Answer (score 0):

`FlutterDownloader.registerCallback` accepts a method which should have positional arguments `id(String data-type)`, `status(int data-type)` and `progress(int data-type)` and your `DownloadManagerCallback` method has different data types rather than specified for `FlutterDownloader.registerCallback`.

So what you have to do is change your `downloadCallback` method positional parameter's types

```
typedef DownloadManagerCallback<T> = void Function(
String id, int status, int progress);
```